# jQuery Wrapp unique Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, grouping

Following are the tags which have been created.

```
<div class="2013"><p>Item 1</p></div>
<div class="2013"><p>Item 2</p></div>
<div class="2012"><p>Item 3</p></div>
<div class="2012"><p>Item 4</p></div>
<div class="2012"><p>Item 5</p></div>
<div class="2011"><p>Item 6</p></div>
```

I need to arrange them as the following using jQuery.

```
<div id="2013">
    <div class="2013"><p>Item 1</p></div>
    <div class="2013"><p>Item 2</p></div>
</div>
<div id="2012">
    <div class="2012"><p>Item 3</p></div>
    <div class="2012"><p>Item 4</p></div>
    <div class="2012"><p>Item 5</p></div>
</div>
<div id="2012">
    <div class="2011"><p>Item 6</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @SayemAhmed I tried to get the unique elements using jQuery's `.unique` function and wrap them around but it didnt work out very well.

Comment: iterate through each DOM and check if other has same class...if same class found then append it to array first or class key and then display it as you need....simple

Comment: @chamarakera: Then show us some sample code. This way people will be able to help you better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
//here find out the divs you want to target - this filter is for demo only
var $targets = $('div');

var classes = {};
$targets.each(function(){
    classes[this.className] = this.className;
})

$.each(classes, function(key, value){
    $targets.filter('.' + key).wrapAll($('<div />', {
        id: key
    }))
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wxQWL/)

Comment: Not a perfect solution. The parent div's do not have id=2013

Comment: @MarsOne it was a bug fixed

Answer (score 1):

using `each` and `wrapAll()`

try this..

```
var tempObj={};
$('div').each(function(){
  var className=this.className;
  tempObj[className]=className;
});
$.each(tempObj,function(i,v){
  $('.'+v).wrapAll('<div id="'+v+'"></div>')
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/)